# Mysqli query multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a query that then displays certain results based on previous queries

The idea is that when someone logs into the page, it gets the session username and and saves it to a variable, from there the first query selects a row based on the session username, gets that value and does the same in the second query but on a different table this time getting the row based on the result from query 1 and query 3 is same as two and then its meant to echo it out

here's the code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","boats4u");
$search = $_SESSION['myusername'];

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to database". mysqli_connect_error();

}
$pre_res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ownerNo FROM boatowner WHERE email ='$search'");
$pre_res = $pre_res -> fetch_assoc();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT boatNo FROM boatforrent WHERE ownerNo ='$pre_res'");
$result = $result -> fetch_assoc();
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM boatviewing WHERE boatNo = '$result'");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Client No</th>
<th>Boat No</th>
<th>View Date</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['clientNo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['boatNo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['viewDate']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['comment']."</td>";
}
echo "</table>";


?>
```

this is what displays

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   E:\Download\Xampp\htdocs\owner.php on line 29

If I remove the first query then it no errors but obviously the search doesn't work then

any help appreciated

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you? Have you double checked the variable in question of line 29 is actually in form of string and not in form of array? As it is an array, have you looked inside that variable and could you see some data?

Comment: Did you know that you can make use of the relations between the tables within a single SQL statement already?

Comment: Yeah im not very SQL savvy it is only a small task so i just kept it simple for myself, i always trip up over little things, thanks for quick response

Comment: well, you're doing yourself a favor to use it right for the small things. otherwise things just aren't simple.

Answer (score 3):

You should do one query and also parametize the *`search`* parameter. Something along the lines like:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
   SELECT boatviewing.*       
   FROM boatowner owner
   LEFT JOIN boatforrent ON boatforrent.ownerNo = owner.ownerNo 
   LEFT JOIN boatviewing ON boatviewing.boatNo = boatforrent.boatNo
   WHERE owner.email = ?
');

$stmt->bind_param("s", $search);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Such code is normally more robust against SQL injection and it's also easier in case you change your database layout.

Next to that you actually run one query instead of three which allows the database to optimize data-retrieval and keeps roundtrips between the PHP script and the database server low.